# Відповідник до слова бюстгальтер

Tags: іменники, відповідник

Цікавить літературний відповідник до слова "бюстгальтер".

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/biusthalter) знаходжу:

> **персанок, станик** та ін.

Однак у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/persanok) перше слово відсутнє, друге - діалектизм, відповідно й усі інші - новотвори.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **бюстга́льтер** літературне. Зокрема його фіксує [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6301&page=230), наводячи цитати Антоненка-Давидовича:

> БЮСТГА́ЛЬТЕР, а, *ч[оловічий рід]*. Предмет жіночої білизни, який підтримує груди. *В коридорі різко загупотіли кроки .. Паля Степанівна прожогом засунула за бюстгальтер листа* (Б. Антоненко-Давидович); *Вузький бюстгальтер стягував її груди* (Б. Харчук); *– Манько, кінчай базар, у секцію Любки підкинули безрозмірні імпортні бюстгальтери* (А. Крижанівський).

— а також [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) і [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/bjustghaljter).

Так само як і слово **[лі́фчик](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48163&page=1519)**, наведене у [відповіді Iva_ukr](/a/4904) — хоча останнє має й інші значення.

Також є слово *[ліф](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48158&page=1519)*, яке, однак, уже вважається розмовним в цьому значенні.

Answer (score 4):

У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B1%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) знаходимо:

> **ЛІ́ФЧИК** (частина жіночої білизни, що облягає груди), БЮСТГА́ЛЬТЕР.

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/lifchyk) також знаходимо це слово:

> **ЛІ́ФЧИК**, а, чол.
>   1. Предмет дитячої або жіночої білизни, який облягає груди. Вона швидко натягла панчохи, взула черевички і наділа ліфчик (Наталя Забіла, Катруся.., 1955, 4); Лукерка.. прала всякий дріб'язок: занавіски, ліфчики, рушники(Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 127).
>   2. Зменш. до ліф.

В [Орфографічному словнику](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%84%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA) також знаходимо це слово.

Answer (score 3):

[Словник чужомовних слів Павла Штепи](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt)

> ліфчик — *див.* бюстгалтер
>   бюстголдер — нагрудниця, *див.* ліф

Для порівняння

> бюст — погруддя

Можна також вжити з СУМ

> [Нагрудник](http://sum.in.ua/s/naghrudnyk) Фартух або частина фартуха, яка надягається на груди для захисту їх від чого-небудь.

Comment: Нагрудниця — цікавий варіант. Можна спробувати навіть [нагрудник](http://sum.in.ua/s/naghrudnyk). Хоча авторка, мені здається, в цьому разі цікавилась саме літературними варіантами, а не спробами позбутися іншомовних слів (хоча, може, я неправильно зрозумів).